# Extracting raw gps messages with GNSS

Tags: gps, gnss

I am using GNSS to see the position of the satellite that is sending the gps messages. When using GNSS, the decoder only gives me the coordinates for the receiver at the given time. What I want is to see the original gps messages with time and position of the transmitter (satellite) instead of the receivers position at the time of receiving the signal.

Does anyone know how to do this? I am using the .dat file that is provided in the tutorial of GNSS and wish to see the gps messages in that file before any processing is done. There might be a way to tweak the program/config file or maybe there is a way to see the original gps messages. Any tip would helpful and much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It's rather straightforward to see the raw data transmitted from any given GPS Satellite, using the details provided in the GPS Signal Specification (for example: see https://www.gps.gov/technical/ps/1995-SPS-signal-specification.pdf)

This would be to demodulate the RF data itself (the OP may be interested in seeing the raw framed data after demodulation is already performed by a receiver which this is not answering).

The process to demodulate the RF signal is as follows:

Translate the signal centered about the carrier at 1575.42 MHz to samples at complex I and Q baseband, optionally through an intermediate frequency.

Create the C/A code for a particular satellite of interest.

Correlate using the code to what otherwise appears like captured noise in the received signal.

The received signal will inevitably be at an offset frequency from the exact 1575.42 MHz carrier, up to +/-5KHz typically due to Doppler from the relative motion of the satellite and the receiver, as well as clock offsets. The correlation process involves a frequency search and carrier removal. Once removed the correlation results will be consistent with the raw data from the satellite (20 repetitions of each C/A code are used to transmit each bit!).

The specific details would be more than I can explain here in a short post, but I am actively teaching a course that just started where I go through this process in great detail, in Python, using actual GPS signals. If anyone still wants to jump in the link to the course is at [dsprelated.com/courses](https://dsprelated.com/courses) and titled "DSP for Software Radio". (and is offered a couple times each year through this site as well as the Boston Section IEEE).